# Сео теги в head

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, seo

Что имеем:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Магазин</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One|Roboto:300,400,500,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'market/desktop/application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie7-8.css">
    <![endif]-->
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'market/desktop/application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
    <%= render @p::Subdivision %>
</head>
<body class="auto">
    <div id="page">
    <% if controller_name != 'error' %>
      <div class="error_report modals"></div>
    <% end %>
        <div id="header">
            <%= render @p::Header %>
        </div><!--header-->
        <div id="bar">
            <%= render @p::Bar %>
        </div><!--bar-->
        <div id="wrapper" class="container">
            <div id="top">
                <div class="rows">
                    <div class="left">
                        <div class="slider slider1">
                          <%= render @p::Slider %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timetable">
                          <%= render @p::Timetable %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="timetable_hidden">
                        </div>
                        <div class="brands">
                          <%= render @p::Brands %>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

На этой страничке я рендерю остальные. Сейчас столкнулся с такой проблемой нужно для каждого товара написать свои SEO-теги, но страница с HEAD у меня одна, как быть? использовать <% if controller_name == 'бла-бла' %> не хочу, ибо контроллеров будет очень много. Как можно вопрос решить по-другому?

Comment: Не совсем поняла, как у вас приложение организовано. Если это стандартные рельсовые вьюхи, то с этой задачей прекрасно справляется хелпер `content_for`

Comment: Да,я это нашел, но пока не понимаю как его использовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае есть смысл использовать хелпер content_for (в том числе и для ваших скриптов с картами из предыдущего вопроса). Работает это примерно так.

В лэйауте (полагаю, application.html.erb):

```
<% if content_for?(:seo_tags) %> 
  <%= yield (:seo_tags) %>
<% else %> # на случай, если где-то не будете использовать content_for
  <title>Магазин</title> # дальше можно добавить общие description и keywords
<% end %>
```

Во вьюхе products#show:

```
<% content_for :seo_tags do %>
  <title>@product.title</title> # и точно так же description и keywords, которые я полагаю у вас в самом продукте хранятся
<% end %>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, почти так же сделал)